# Can you control chrome once it's in application mode (Python)?

Tags: python, puppeteer, chromium

I haven't been able to find anyone asking the same question as this anywhere on the internet. This is what my code currently looks like.

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

    async def run():
        browser = await launch(headless=False,
                               args=['--disable-infobars',
                                     '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled',
                                     "--disable-blink-features",
                                     '--window-size=432,630',
                                     '--app=https://accounts.google.com/login'])
    
    
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run())
```

Basically, if I start at https://accounts.google.com/login , how would I go about going to a different webpage for example?

Comment: use chromedriver instead

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pyppeteer.page.Page.goto`](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html?highlight=goto#pyppeteer.page.Page.goto) to navigate to a different site, for example:

```
await page.goto(url)
```

Comment: The problem that I had with this, is that when I create a page by doing 
page = await browser.newPage() 
this opens a page outside of the application.